# "Connection refused: localhost:8089" error (using xampp)

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

I use xampp to run a local server and this is the first time that I experience this message while accessing localhost:

[image: Message]

When I try to access the localhost without custom port, the response is always blank, but when I set my port to the default (non-custom, the port 80) I receive the same message (error?).

When I try to access the localhost with my custom port at browser's private window it works sometimes that I refresh the same page. Else, the page gets blank. (I also cleaned browser's cache on non-private window. I see the complete page's HTML to check if it's blank or not)

And I'm seeing that my custom port is being used by httpd.exe (only httpd.exe), so it should work. Note: the initial port of xampp was 80, but since this such "Connection refused" error started (right now) I tried to change it to check if it'd solve, but it didn't solve.

[image: 8089]

Any ideas about what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by disabling the Opera Turbo. The Opera's Browser had this option enabled. Looks like someone had this problem too, but posted in [Opera forums](http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1839530/connection-refused-122-252-226-2178080/p1).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and searched the net and tried every possible solution, configuration, firewall exemption etc etc. Finally narrowed it down to the interference on installation of FileZilla client from Avira (free) antivirus. It was still actively working against Filezilla behind the scenes. I did a complete uninstall of Xampp, FileZilla client and Avira, reinstalled the first two, finally successfully established connection, then re-installed Avira with exceptions for the FTP apps.